# Reading files from Mapped network drive is quite slow when compared to USB in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, crc32

I'm copying files from USB and network mapped share drive to my Server. Before copying files I 'm doing certain validations and once the validation is okay then I'm copying the files to the destination. Significant validation is **CRC** validation using the System.Interop.Services. All this is done by a Windows Service written in C#.

Problem : Both my USB and Mapped network drive modules go through the same code i.e. code that does the CRC validation and copy.

From USB if i start my process with a 800MB file then the CRC validation takes maximum 30 secs and copying in maximum 1 minute.

From Network Mapped Drive if i start my process with a 800MB file then the CRC validation takes around  10 minutes and copying in maximum 1 minute.

1. Why is this difference ?
2. Why the same operation from USB is much faster than the Network mapped drive ?
3. Is it just because of the Ethernet speed ? or something else technically ?

If it is with the speed then for me to copy the file it takes only 1 minute in both USB as well as Mapped Network Drive. Only while performing the CRC (again same code & logic for both USB & NT mapped drive) I'm observing this difference.

Addition Info : I have used .Net Framework, C#, wNetAddConnection for mapping network drive.

Request your expert opinion on the same.

Code for CRC Validation :

```
internal class CRC 
{ 

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "CRC.dll" )] 
public static extern int Validate665Loadset( string pszLoadsetPath );

}
```

This is what i'm calling and it returns the value. If it is ZERO then content is valid else not. Thats the logic.

Comment: Is this USB 2.0? I would suspect transfer rates but could be a number of things

Comment: I think this may help you http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885189

Comment: @Sayse:The server box is WindowsXP SP3 one and i believe it would be 2.0. They directly plugs in the USB in that box and then copy or plug in a laptop and map the laptop drive and then do the copy. I would like to highlight again .., copying is pretty quick in both USB as well as mapped drive. Problem is when it reads and performs the CRC validation.

Comment: With the edit, whatever is causing the slowness: it is inside crc.dll; *probably* lack of buffering.

Comment: @Marc: I agree with you. Only thing which is baffling is, the same buffering or streaming issues should cause problem when we do the validation with USB as the source. But it is not. That's why I couldn't conclude on anything. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the file? Yes, it is entirely possible that there are *simply very different bandwidths*, but CRC validation taking 10 times as long as copying **for the same origin** (network) suggests the code is doing something funky - since both *basically* involve reading all the bytes, they should be about the same (caveat: the OS can optimize the copy scenario in some cases - for example copying a single file over multiple NICs at the same time - which won't be possible if using the file as a stream). I *suspect* the first thing to look at is the buffer size; or possibly adding an explicit `BufferedStream`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Additional Info : My content size is 800 MB and it contains multiple files (may 20 - 40 files). I do the CRC for the contents validity (corrupted or not). Same code works within 30 secs if the source is USB. Problem is only if it is from a network drive. I 'm not sure about the bytes whether 4096 or something else. I will copy the code here.

Comment: internal class CRC
        {
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "CRC.dll" )]
            public static extern int Validate665Loadset( string pszLoadsetPath );
        }

Comment: @Vikineese google reports no matches for `Validate665Loadset`, so there is nothing I can say to that. If the implementation is bad: then it is bad. But frankly, this stopped being a C# / .NET question as soon as you p/invoked, and started being a support question for crc.dll